# JFrame Window not showing any content unless resized

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have an Interface class that extends JFrame. I am creating 3 JPanels and adding them to a Container (Border Layout) in different areas of the layout.

When I run the application, nothing shows but a blank window and a title. If I resize the application it will then show all the content and work as intended.

I'm not sure what I did differently this time, I've used this method before and it works in previous programs.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is my Interface Class Constructor code: http://pastebin.com/4UyEXsBr

Code:

```
public class Interface extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

private Container contentPane;

private JPanel buttonPanel, userPanel;

private JButton loginButton, createUserButton, logoutButton, withdrawButton, depositButton, switchToRegisterButton, switchToLoginButton;

private JLabel headerLabel, inputTopJTFLabel, inputPW1JPFLabel, toastLabel, inputPW2JPFLabel;

public JTextField inputTopJTF;
public JPasswordField inputPW1JPF, inputPW2JPF;

JRootPane rootPane;

public Interface(int width, int height, String title) {

    //Setting up Interface
    setTitle(title);
    setSize(width, height);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLocation(100,100);
    setVisible(true);

    Font header = new Font("TimesRoman", Font.PLAIN, 50);

    ///////////////////////BUTTON PANEL///////////////////////

    //Button Panel
    buttonPanel = new JPanel();

    //Buttons
    //loginButton
    loginButton = new JButton("Login");
    loginButton.addActionListener(this);
    loginButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //switchToRegisterButton
    switchToRegisterButton = new JButton("New User?");
    switchToRegisterButton.addActionListener(this);
    switchToRegisterButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //switchToLoginButton
    switchToLoginButton = new JButton("Switch to Login");
    switchToLoginButton.addActionListener(this);
    switchToLoginButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    switchToLoginButton.setVisible(false);

    //createUserButton
    createUserButton = new JButton("Register");
    createUserButton.addActionListener(this);
    createUserButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    createUserButton.setVisible(false);

    //logoutButton
    logoutButton = new JButton("Logout");
    logoutButton.addActionListener(this);
    logoutButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    logoutButton.setVisible(false);

    //withdrawButton
    withdrawButton = new JButton("Withdraw");
    withdrawButton.addActionListener(this);
    withdrawButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    withdrawButton.setVisible(false);

    //depositButton
    depositButton = new JButton("Deposit");
    depositButton.addActionListener(this);
    depositButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    depositButton.setVisible(false);

    //Adding items to buttonPanel
    buttonPanel.add(loginButton);
    buttonPanel.add(switchToRegisterButton);
    buttonPanel.add(switchToLoginButton);
    buttonPanel.add(createUserButton);
    buttonPanel.add(logoutButton);
    buttonPanel.add(withdrawButton);
    buttonPanel.add(depositButton);

    ///////////////BODY PANEL//////////////////////

    //Body Panel
    userPanel = new JPanel();
    userPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(userPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));

    //JTextFields
    //inputTopJTF
    Dimension inputTopJTFDimension = new Dimension(100, 20);
    inputTopJTF = new JTextField();
    inputTopJTF.setMaximumSize(inputTopJTFDimension);

    //inputPW1JPF
    Dimension inputPW1JPFDimension = new Dimension(100, 20);
    inputPW1JPF = new JPasswordField();
    inputPW1JPF.setMaximumSize(inputPW1JPFDimension);

    //inputPW2JPF
    Dimension inputPW2JPFDimension = new Dimension(100, 20);
    inputPW2JPF = new JPasswordField();
    inputPW2JPF.setMaximumSize(inputPW2JPFDimension);
    inputPW2JPF.setVisible(false);

    //JLabels
    //toastLabel
    toastLabel = new JLabel("Please sign in or create new account.");
    toastLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //inputTopJTFLabel
    inputTopJTFLabel = new JLabel("Username:");
    inputTopJTFLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //inputPW1JPFLabel
    inputPW1JPFLabel = new JLabel("Password:");
    inputPW1JPFLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);

    //inputPW2JPFLabel
    inputPW2JPFLabel = new JLabel("Confirm Password:");
    inputPW2JPFLabel.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    inputPW2JPFLabel.setVisible(false);

    //Adding items to userPanel
    userPanel.add(toastLabel);
    userPanel.add(inputTopJTFLabel);
    userPanel.add(inputTopJTF);
    userPanel.add(inputPW1JPFLabel);
    userPanel.add(inputPW1JPF);
    userPanel.add(inputPW2JPFLabel);
    userPanel.add(inputPW2JPF);

///////////////CONTENT PANE/////////////////////

//Content Pane
contentPane = getContentPane();

//JLabels
//headerLabel
headerLabel = new JLabel("Bank", SwingConstants.CENTER);
headerLabel.setFont(header);

//PAGE_START
contentPane.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

//LINE_START

//CENTER
contentPane.add(userPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

//LINE_END

//PAGE_END
contentPane.add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

userPanel.setFocusable(true);
userPanel.requestFocus();

//Default Button
rootPane = getRootPane();
rootPane.setDefaultButton(loginButton);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

call

```
setVisible(true);
```

in last line .because component added after line setvisible will not be shown until you call `repaint(),revalidate()`.when you resize ,repaint() method get called and frame will visible correctly .so call `setvisible` after add all component

after line `rootPane.setDefaultButton(loginButton);` call `setvisible`

```
rootPane.setDefaultButton(loginButton);
setVisible(true);//after add all component to frame call setvisible method
```

[this is full working code](http://pastebin.com/q9d2fpi5)

Comment: Thanks a lot! That would be why it worked in my last program and not this one. I placed a setVisible(true); but at the beginning of the constructor, rather than the end.

Comment: *"will not be shown until you call repaint()"* - Actually, even then, they are likely not to be shown, you should call `revalidate`, followed by `repaint` - Also, don't link to the code, you can include in your answer, links die after time, making your answer less relevant ;)